# Al hacer un "hola mundo" en netbeans me sale eso y mas cosas

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como configura es parte para que solo me salga "hola mundo"

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que al elegir el proyecto que has creado elegiste crear un proyecto MAVEN, y lo que hace es comprobar mogollón de cosas que mantiene MAVEN automáticamente, como por ejemplo las dependencias.

Si creas el mismo proyecto con ANT en vez de con MAVEN veras que se aligera bastante "todo" eso que te sale.